How to Vaidate access token in OAuth 2.0?
I am wondering how to validate the access_token provided by authentication server which is Github in my case? Like if it is expired or still valid etc. And on what URL I can go and type of requestbody need to be sent etc.
I have searched it on Github and on web but couldn't get satisfactory response.
